# OnKeyDown event not updating instantly, OnKeyUp is

Tags: events, dart, dart-html

I just started looking at `Dart`. I am updating a `<p>` tag when editing an `<input type="form">`.

However, when I use the `onKeyDown` event, it is not updating instantly but is delayed by 1 keypress. So if I press AAA it will only display AA.

If I use `onKeyUp`, AAA will give me AAA.

Why is it not updating as expecting when using `onKeyDown`?

Here is the code:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

TextInputElement inputText;
ParagraphElement pargraphText;

void main() {
  inputText = querySelector("#text");
  pargraphText = querySelector("#paragraphText");

  // inputText.onKeyDown.listen(updateTekst);
  inputText.onKeyUp.listen(updateTekst);
}

void updateTekst(Event e) {
  pargraphText.text = inputText.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the input element doesn't have the value yet. It gets the value on keyPress or keyUp but not yet on keyDown.
If you use the value from the event instead from the input field, then you get the value even for the first keyDown.

You can use e.keyCode (charCode is not set on keyDown)

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

...

// doesn't distinguish between upper/lower case (you have to check e.shiftKey)
UTF8.decode([e.keyCode]);
```